# Why can't I access characters in strings in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.  I've seen online that characters in a string can be accessed using normal indexing (e.g a_string_variable(1:5)) however when I do this I get a 1x0 empty string array or even worst an error.

I've attached a screen shot of my Matlab command window below to show you what I'm doing and the error I am getting.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A string formed with the double quotes " is treated as if the entire string is *one* element of the variable. Kind of like a cell array. This is a type of classdef OOP object.

A string formed with the single quotes ' is treated as an array of characters, with each character being one element of the variable.

To get the behavior you are apparently wanting, use the single ' quotes.

Comment: And if you've already got a `string` array in a variable, call the `char(...)` function on it to convert it to a char array. (You can also use `{...}` indexing in to the string array to "pop out" one of the string element contents as char.) And the `string(...)` array on the results if you want to convert it back to a string.